# Deploying/Installing Laravel application with ServiceProviders requiring database connection

Tags: php, laravel, migration

**Scenario:**
Performing a fresh deploy of an existing Laravel application (i.e. production, Travis, locally, etc.)

**Problem:**
When running the Laravel migrations you run `php artisan migrate` which first boots up an instance of the application before it can actually run the migrations.

Included in instantiating an instance of the application is booting up any registered service providers. Sometimes one of those `ServiceProvider`'s could rely on a connection to the database.

This ultimately means that in order to run `php artisan migrate` you would have had to already have your database migrated, otherwise you will get the error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException] SQLSTATE[42S02]:
>   Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database.table' doesn't exist ...

**Potential Solution:**

One solution is to wrap any calls in the `ServiceProvider` in a `try - catch` to allow the first `artisan migrate` to execute, like so:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    foreach ($this->getPermissions() as $permission) {
        Gate::define($permission->name, function ($user) use ($permission) {
            return $user->hasPermission($permission);
        });
    }
}

protected function getPermissions()
{
    try {
        return Permission::with('roles')->get();
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
        return [];
    }
}
```

**Question:**
Is there any better way to complete this process of deploying, particularly  without needing to add code to the actual `ServiceProvider`?

Comment: As long as you have configured your `.env` or `app\config` settings, you should be able to run `composer install` followed by `php artisan migrate` without an issue.

Comment: You shouldn't query data in the `boot` method.

Comment: @tkausl I'm listening, care to elaborate?

Comment: Don't query everything you _might_ need at startup, query _when_ you actually need it. [Lazy Loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading)

Comment: @tkausl That makes sense, but I think there are occasions when you do want to query on every request into the application. Take my example of permissions, I do want to check that on every request into the application, except for I guess CLI commands.

Comment: I take that back I do want permissions even on CLI commands.

Comment: Your example code doesn't make much sense as it gets all permissions and throws them away right after. What do you do with the permissions? Any real-world example?

Comment: Ill edit the post with a real example

Comment: In this case I wouldn't even bother defining all the permissions in `Gate` and instead just call `$user->hasPermission()` directly.

Comment: this is going way beyond the scope of the original question, but anyway there are reasons to use `Gate` such as the blade `@can` directive, a cleaner more expressive way to authorize in the rest of the application, and an easier way to add more complicated authorization logic in the future. If you want to chat abt it I would be happy to, I am certainly up for talking about writing better code, but this is well beyond this question at this point

Comment: Loading policies this way was used in Laracast screencast. However I totally find it unnecessary. Policies are much better and powerful, and you can use @can with them.